# Constructing a string of a specific length starting with a specific prefix

Tags: c++, string, performance, append

I need to construct a string of a specific length starting with a specific prefix. Is there any faster way (**in terms of performance**) to achieve the objective of the following piece of code? Would it be of any help to use `char*` here?

```
int strLen = 15;
string prefix = "1234"; // could be a number of any length less than strLen
int prefixLen = prefix.length();
string str = prefix;
for(int i=0;i<strLen-prefixLen;i++)
{
    str.append("9"); // use character '9' as filler
}
printf("str: %s \n", str.c_str());
```

Sample prefix and output:

```
prefix: 123, str:  123999999999999
prefix: 1234, str: 123499999999999
```

The only thing I do not want changed in this code is the type of `'prefix'` which should remain `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
std::string content(15, '9'); // start off with all 9s
content.replace(0, 4, "1234"); // replace the first four characters etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int StrLength = 15;
    string PreFix = "1234";
    string RestOfStr(StrLength - PreFix.length(), '9');
    cout << PreFix << RestOfStr << endl;
```

the string class has an overloaded Constructor, taking a size and a char.
The constructor will create a string object filled with the char repeated x amount of times

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
unsigned strLen(15);
std::string prefix("1234");
prefix += std::string(strLen - prefix.length(), '9');
```